creating helper methods for rendertreebuilder in a world of sequence numbers
I'm using blazor - and writing stuff to draw graphs and I'm finding a lot of repeated code - like:

       // Draw X-axis
        builder.OpenElement(100, "line");
        builder.AddAttribute(101, "x1", graphArea.X);
        builder.AddAttribute(102, "y1", graphArea.Y + graphArea.Height);
        builder.AddAttribute(103, "x2", graphArea.X + graphArea.Width);
        builder.AddAttribute(104, "y2", graphArea.Y + graphArea.Height);
        builder.AddAttribute(105, "stroke", color);
        builder.AddAttribute(106, "stroke-width", AxisThickness);
        builder.CloseElement();

        // Draw X-axis ticks and labels
        for (var i = 0; i <= HorizontalTicks; i++)
        {
            var x = graphArea.X + i * graphArea.Width / HorizontalTicks;
            var date = dateMin.AddTicks((dateMax - dateMin).Ticks * i / HorizontalTicks);

            builder.OpenElement(110, "line");
            builder.AddAttribute(111, "x1", x);
            builder.AddAttribute(112, "y1", graphArea.Y + graphArea.Height);
            builder.AddAttribute(113, "x2", x);
            builder.AddAttribute(114, "y2", graphArea.Y + graphArea.Height + 5 * AxisThickness);
            builder.AddAttribute(115, "stroke", color);
            builder.AddAttribute(106, "stroke-width", AxisThickness);
            builder.CloseElement();

what I really sort of want is to be able to say something like builder.AddLine( x, y, x+width, x + height, Color.Red);
but of course then I run into lots of warnings of programmatic sequence numbers and so on.  Is there a way to do it without tanking performance?

Any particular reason you are no just creating a razor file or a static RenderFragment ?

The advice is to "follow linenumbers" and you can get those in a default parameter with [CallerLineNumber].
Something like this will work:
void AddDiv(RenderTreeBuilder builder, string text, [CallerLineNumber] int lineNumber = 0)
{
    int sequence = lineNumber * 100;

#pragma warning disable ASP0006 // Do not use non-literal sequence numbers
    builder.OpenElement(sequence++, "div");
    builder.AddContent(sequence++, text);
#pragma warning restore ASP0006 // Do not use non-literal sequence numbers
    builder.CloseElement();
}

That 100 should be a constant and accomodate the largest block you are going to add.

Maybe you could try use variable seq from beginning and return the seq number after the method.
    public static class RenderTreeBuilderExtensions
    {
        public static int AddLine(this RenderTreeBuilder builder,int seq, double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2, string stroke = "black", double strokeWidth = 1)
        {
            //if seq is 107,jump to 110
            if (seq % 10 != 0)
            {
                seq=((seq / 10) + 1) * 10;
            }

            builder.OpenElement(seq++, "line");
            builder.AddAttribute(seq++, "x1", x1);
            builder.AddAttribute(seq++, "y1", y1);
            builder.AddAttribute(seq++, "x2", x2);
            builder.AddAttribute(seq++, "y2", y2);
            builder.AddAttribute(seq++, "stroke", stroke);
            builder.AddAttribute(seq++, "stroke-width", strokeWidth);
            builder.CloseElement();
            return seq;
        }
    }

        protected override void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
        {
            int seq = 0;
            ...
            builder.OpenElement(seq++, "div"); 
            ...
            // Draw X-axis
            seq = builder.AddLine(seq, graphArea.X, graphArea.Y + graphArea.Height, graphArea.X + graphArea.Width, raphArea.Y + graphArea.Height, color, AxisThickness);

            // Draw X-axis ticks and labels
            for (var i = 0; i <= HorizontalTicks; i++)
            {
                ...

                seq = builder.AddLine(seq, graphArea.X, graphArea.Y + graphArea.Height, graphArea.X + graphArea.Width, raphArea.Y + graphArea.Height, color, AxisThickness);

            }
            ...
        }


There are several approaches you can take to this.
Regions
Microsoft suggests you use OpenRegion/CloseRegion. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/advanced-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-8.0#guidance-and-conclusions Point 3.
Something like:
builder.OpenRegion(n);
//...  this block has it's own sequence numbers 
builder.CloseRegion();

However, it's instructive to look at some Razor compiler generated code for a loop.
Here's a simple page:
@page "/"

<ul>
    @foreach(var country in _countries )
    {
        <li>@country</li>
    }
</ul>

@code{
    private List<string> _countries = new () {"France", "Spain", "UK"};
}

And the generated code [without all the commenting and other stuff]
namespace SO78951352.Components.Pages;

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;

[RouteAttribute("/")]
public partial class Default : ComponentBase
{
    private List<string> _countries = new() { "France", "Spain", "UK" };

    protected override void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder __builder)
    {
        __builder.OpenElement(1, "ul");
        foreach (var country in _countries)
        {
            __builder.OpenElement(2, "li");
            __builder.AddContent(3, country);
            __builder.CloseElement();
        }
        __builder.CloseElement();
    }
}

What's evident is:

either the RenderTreeBuilder gracefully handles the numbering within the loop, or
the Microsoft Dev Team have made a serious error.

Option 2 obviously isn't true, so RenderTreeBuilder handles it and you don't need to worry.
To quote from the documentation [ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/advanced-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-8.0#guidance-and-conclusions - point 5]:

For loops, the sequence numbers should increase in your source code, not in terms of runtime behavior. The fact that, at runtime, the numbers repeat is how the diffing system realises you're in a loop.

Render Fragments
You could write components to handle each drawing element, but they are overkill and expensive.  Instead you can write static RenderFragment delegate methods.
First a minimal base razor file that will compile to hold your methods.
public abstract class RazorBase
{
    protected abstract void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder);

    public RenderFragment Content => (builder) => BuildRenderTree(builder);
}

And then razor files like this with static methods to produce the markup.
@inherits RazorBase

@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering

@code {
    public readonly record struct AlertData(string? Message);

    public static RenderFragment<string> RenderItem  => (string country) => __builder =>
    {
        <li>@country</li>
    };

    public static RenderFragment<AlertData> RenderAlert => (AlertData data) => __builder =>
    {
        <div class="alert alert-primary">@data.Message</div>
    };
}

Which you use like this:
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<ul>
    @foreach(var country in _countries )
    {
        @ListComponents.RenderItem(country);
    }
</ul>

@foreach (var country in _countries)
{
    @ListComponents.RenderAlert(new ListComponents.AlertData(country));
}

@code{
    private List<string> _countries = new () {"France", "Spain", "UK"};
}

You can create the render fragments Graph.DrawLine(LineDataObject) and simple data objects for your various graph objects.
If you want to view compiled files here's a Note to Self gist on how: https://gist.github.com/ShaunCurtis/0a487f4d0970267f871bea5ef77e4e42
See this gist on why you shouldn't do auto-sequencing:

https://gist.github.com/SteveSandersonMS/ec232992c2446ab9a0059dd0fbc5d0c3

And this is the MS Docs information:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/advanced-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-8.0#guidance-and-conclusions


I don't think that a region solves the for-loop or if-else problems.

@HenkHolterman - See my updated answer.
